# Are current ethereum opcodes prices in pyethereum updated?

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, opcode, pyethereum, py-evm

I am not an expert in opcodes for Ethereum, but I am wondering if their prices here [https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/opcodes.py] are updated as the latest version used by other clients?

If not how to update it?

Answer (score 0):

That repo was marked as deprecated quite [recently](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/commit/180ab66e0833fa3bacd59e4bfbfae966077018a0).

The new work is being done at https://github.com/ethereum/py-evm.

Answer (score 0):

As long as no vote was cast by the majority to change the OPCODE prices, every client will have the same prices, otherwise they will fork and create an isolated network. If the majority casts a vote for changing the prices, you will recognize this by Ethereum being hardforked into 2 different Ethereum Blockchains (like ETH and ETC).